# No Permission error using Firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I am trying to add Firebase for the first time to an ionic application. I have set up my project and referenced the javascript files however when I run the application I see the error 'Error: Permission Denied'

I have not yet set up authentication in my app but, if I am understanding things properly I shouldn't need to do this while I am just testing.

My index.html contains the following:

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

While the app.js has the following lines:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'firebase'])
.factory("Items", function($firebaseArray) {
    var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://todo-83e58.firebaseio.com/items");
    return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
})

.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $ionicListDelegate, Items) {
    $scope.items = Items;


$scope.addItem = function () {
    var name = prompt("what do you need to buy?");
    if (name) {
        $scope.items.$add({"name": name});
    }
};
```

I would be grateful for any pointers on how to get the basics right as I have tried following the information on the Firebase site and I seem to have it all set up correctly. Am I misunderstanding the authentication or shouldI be able to write to the database without setting this up first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds that your Security & Rules isn't giving you access to `items`. Please make sure to spend some time reading the [S&R documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#configuring_rules).

If you are only testing the application and don't want to care about it now  just set it to full read and write.

On the new console go to Database > Rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I must have been following an old course or something because it appeared to me that the default was full read and write but this clearly isn't the case.